# Add New Column to TableView - JAVA FX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have class Item (name, id, amount etc) and class Rating. Each Item has ratelist. I made funcion which count average for product (by taking item_id) and i have TableView with Items. Now i have 2 problems. I have to add that average to TableView (as new Columny "Average") and later made that each product will have their average (that's problem when funcion is taking item_id but it have to).

Item class:

```
public class Item implements Serializable {

static int idCounter=0;
@Id
@Column(name = "car_id") // Mam swiadomosc
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
        @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy ="increment")
int id;
@Column(name = "item_name",length = 100,nullable =false)
String name;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "Item_status", length = 100, nullable = false)
Itemstatus status;
@Column(name = "weight")
double weight;
@Column(name = "amount")
public int amount;
@Column(name = "price")
double price;
@Column(name = "WH_name",length = 100,nullable = false)
String WHname;
transient public int bought = 0;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="car_id")
public List<Rating> RatingList=new ArrayList<>();
```

TableView+ List of Items:

```
private ObservableList<Item> getItem() {
    ObservableList<Item> items=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    FulfillmentCenter F1 = FulfillmentCenterContainer.search( comboBox.getValue());

    if(!comboBox.getValue().equals("dowolny"))
        items=FXCollections.observableArrayList(F1.ProductList);
    else
        for(int i = 0; i< FulfillmentCenterContainer.WareHouseList.size(); i++){
            items.addAll(FulfillmentCenterContainer.WareHouseList.get(i).ProductList);
        }
    return items;
}
 private TableView<Item> getTable(){

    TableColumn<Item,String> column1 = new TableColumn<>("Name of Item");
    column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

    TableColumn<Item,String> column5 = new TableColumn<>("Status of Item");
    column5.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("status"));

    TableColumn<Item, Double> column2 = new TableColumn<>("Price in $");
    column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));

    TableColumn<Item, Double> column6 = new TableColumn<>("Weight");
    column6.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("weight"));


    TableColumn<Item,Integer> column7 = new TableColumn<>("Amount of Item");
    column7.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("amount"));

    TableColumn<Item,String> column4 = new TableColumn<>("Name of Warehouse");
    column4.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("WHname"));

    TableColumn<Item,Integer> column3 = new TableColumn<>("ID of Item");
    column3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));



    tableView=new TableView<>();
    tableView.setItems(getItem());
    tableView.getColumns().addAll(column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7);
    pane.getChildren().add(tableView);
    tableView.setMinWidth(643);
    GridPane.setConstraints(tableView,0,0,1,10);
    addButtonToTable();
    tultip(tableView);
    getList();

    return tableView;
}
```

dowolny= any
And func to get Rating :

```
public double averageRate(int item_id){

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Integer> criteria = builder.createQuery( Integer.class );

    Root<Rating> root = criteria.from( Rating.class );
    criteria.select(root.get("mark"));
    criteria.where( builder.equal( root.get( "car_id" ), item_id ) );
    List<Integer> ratingList=session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();

    double average=0;
    double counter=0;
    for( Integer integer: ratingList) {
        //if(idList.get(0))
        average += integer;
        counter++;
    }

    if(counter!=0)
    return average/counter;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I HAVE TO use criteria to get it (i know it could be done easier)

Comment: Post a [mre]: i.e. a complete application (not your whole project) which includes an `Item` class, and displays a table view, indicating what the actual problem is with creating the column you want.

Comment: @James_D done, i added some stuff

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use the `averageRate` method to get the data. You already have the list of ratings in the `Item` object. Using the `averageRate` method will result in a whole bunch of database queries being executed every time you scroll through the table.

Comment: Because my teacher want to use "Criteria" to get average for each Item, so I have to use Criteria

Comment: java naming conventions please .. and why don't you provide the example as suggested by the help page?

Comment: "java naming conventions please" what do you mean?
Also example of what? Screen of GUI or what?

Comment: "Reproducible" means code we can copy, paste and run. This doesn't meet those criteria. [Naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) (note variables should be lower camel case - note, e.g., how the syntax coloring in your post thinks `WHName` is a class name), and should be descriptive.

Comment: I will take care about naming. About reproducible i have a lot of classes and stuff in that project so i prefered to send just necessary. Maybe i will send it to git later

Comment: No, don't post external links to code. No-one wants your whole project on here. Again, read the link for what's required. None of the JPA stuff is really relevant to your question at all, for example, so you should create a project that doesn't use it for the purposes of the question.

Comment: _"java naming conventions please" what do you mean?_ you have access to the internet (obviously ;) so how about writing those words into the search field of your favorite search tool and read what it throws out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like

```
TableColumn<Item, Number> averageRatingColumn = new TableColumn<>("Average rating");
averageRatingColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleDoubleProperty(averageRate(cellData.getValue().getId()));
```

But note this is incredibly inefficient: since your `averageRate(...)` method creates a database query each time it's called, this is going to query the database every time any row in the table is updated, i.e. it will execute multiple database queries any time the user scrolls in the table.

Since you already have the `List<Rating>` in your `Item` class (which is eagerly populated), it's much more efficient to do, e.g.:

```
TableColumn<Item, List<Rating>> averageRatingColumn = new TableColumn<>("Average Rating");
averageRatingColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue().getRatingList()));
averageRatingColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(List<Rating> ratings, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(ratings, empty);
        if (empty || ratings == null) {
            setText("");
        } else if (ratings.isEmpty()) {
            setText("No ratings");
        } else {
            double average = ratings.stream().collect(
                Collectors.averagingInt(Rating::getMark));
            setText(String.format("%.2f", average));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: in "New SImpleDouble" etc i have to change to HB.averageRate(...), because it's func from other class and when i do it i get "Bad return type in lambda expression: SimpleDoubleProperty cannot be converted to ObservableValue<Double>"

Comment: @SebastianHalik Yes: my bad; `SimpleDoubleProperty` does not implement `ObservableValue<Double>`. I fixed the type of the column. I encourage you to enable logging in your JPA implementation and note what happens when you scroll the table if you use that approach.

Comment: 2nd option works perfectly, but i prefer do it by using my func. I know that's bad but i have to use Criteria XD

Comment: @SebastianHalik 1st option should "work" with fixed column type (`TableColumn<Item, Number>`). As an aside, when asking about homework problems, you should indicate that it's homework and identify any artificial constraints that are imposed as part of the assignment.

Comment: Thank you man. Works now :)I have to do something similar for other data so i will try by myself or if i will stuck that i will write here. Thank you!